# Мультиязычность

Tags: php, mvc, router

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно впилить мультиязычность.
В строке адреса `\домен\lang\controller\action\id`, если нет lang - редирект на "правильный" адрес. Язык по-умолчанию - вызов константы `Config::SITE_LANGUAGE`
Второй день траю, никак не идёт

---

index.php

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $root = dirname(__DIR__);
    $file = $root . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    if (is_readable($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
});

set_error_handler('Core\Error::errorHandler');
set_exception_handler('Core\Error::exceptionHandler');

$router = new Core\Router();

$router->addRoutes('', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index']);
$router->addRoutes('{controller}',  ['action' => 'index']);
$router->addRoutes('{controller}/', ['action' => 'index']);
$router->addRoutes('{controller}/{action}');
$router->addRoutes('{controller}/{action}/');
$router->addRoutes('{controller}/{action}/{id:\d+}');
$router->addRoutes('{controller}/{action}/{id:\d+}/');

$router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

---

router.php

```
namespace Core;

/**
 * Class Router
 * @package Core
 */

class Router
{
    protected $routes = [];
    protected $parameters = [];

    /**
     * @param $route
     * @param array $parameters
     */
    public function addRoutes($route, $parameters = [])
    {
        $route = preg_replace('/\//', '\\/', $route);
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>[a-z-]+)', $route);
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+):([^\}]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>\2)', $route);
        $route = '/^' . $route . '$/i';
        $this  -> routes[$route] = $parameters;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoutes()
    {
        return $this -> routes;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getParameters()
    {
        return $this -> parameters;
    }

    /**
     * @param $url
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function dispatch($url)
    {
        $url = $this->removeQueryStringVariables($url);

        if ($this->matchRoutes($url)) {
            $controller = $this -> parameters['controller'] . 'Controller';
            $controller = $this -> convertToStudlyCaps($controller);
            $controller = $this -> getNamespaces() . $controller;

            if (class_exists($controller)) {
                $controller_object = new $controller($this -> parameters);
                $action = $this -> parameters['action'];
                $action = $this -> convertToCamelCase($action);

                if (is_callable([$controller_object, $action]) && !isset($this -> parameters['id'])) {
                    $controller_object -> $action();
                }
                elseif (is_callable([$controller_object, $action]) && isset($this -> parameters['id'])) {
                    $id = $this -> parameters['id'];
                    $controller_object -> $action($id);
                }
                else {
                    throw new \Exception("Метода $action (в контроллере $controller_object) нет");
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("Контроллер $controller не найден");
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Роута нет', 404);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $url
     * @return string
     */
    protected function removeQueryStringVariables($url)
    {
        if ($url != '') {
            $parts = explode('&', $url, 2);

            if (strpos($parts[0], '=') === false) {
                $url = $parts[0];
            } else {
                $url = '';
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * @param $url
     * @return bool
     */
    public function matchRoutes($url)
    {
        foreach ($this -> routes as $route => $parameters) {
            if (preg_match($route, $url, $matches)) {

                foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
                    if (is_string($key)) {
                        $parameters[$key] = $match;
                    }
                }

                $this -> parameters = $parameters;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function convertToStudlyCaps($string)
    {
        return str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $string)));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getNamespaces()
    {
        $namespace = 'App\Controllers\\';
        if (array_key_exists('namespace', $this -> parameters)) {
            $namespace .= $this -> parameters['namespace'] . '\\';
        }
        return $namespace;
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return string
     */
    protected function convertToCamelCase($string)
    {
        return lcfirst($this -> convertToStudlyCaps($string));
    }
}
```

Comment: фреймворк используете какой-нибудь?

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко нет, сам сочинял из велосипедов и костылей

Comment: @Lance, а если сами насочиняли, зачем используете роутинг? Потому что это "модно"?

Comment: @DaemonHK Было интересно попробовать, да и почему бы и нет? Если есть чем и на что отговорить - пожалуйста, буду рад и плюс вам в карму. В дополнении: проект для учёбы, реализации разных идей.

Comment: @Lance Если Вы делаете обычный сайт, то достаточно просто настроить работу ссылок, определяя конкретную страницу, категорию, товар, новость и т.д. по алиасу. Честно говоря, я вообще не понимаю, зачем нужен роутинг

Comment: @DaemonHK , как же объяснить-то... Всё иное имеет право жить и здравствовать, но именно этот подход мне в данном конкретном случае интересен сейчас. Мне хочется его развить и получить свою пачку экспериенса после этого. А модно или нет - мне абсолютно безразлично; интерес - вот он мотиватор. То что вы указали - ок, я подумаю, спасибо, честно. Давайте все дружно подскажем мне как решить эту проблему? ))) P.s. хочу и делаю маленький комбайн, для некоторых проектов на локальном сервере, с инфой по разному, ПОПУТНО ищу как воплотить свои идеи и собственно воплощаю (кроме той, что в теме).

Comment: @Lance дак и попробуйте впилить язык в Ваши роуты с обработкой `$router->addRoutes('{lang}/{controller}/{action}/');`

Comment: @DaemonHK делал и так стоит в ветке. Загвоздка в самом роутере - если lang нуль, то редирект?... + как лучше подключить этот самый lang(ini, класс с константами, массив со значениями)? Как лучше и правильней сделать?

Comment: @Lance, если `lang` пустой в адресной строке, то должен браться язык приложения по умолчанию. Подключать лучше через БД (языки должны быть добавляемыми/удаляемыми), но для начала и массива в настройках хватит

Comment: @DaemonHK оформите свой последний коммент как ответ - плюсану. Идея понравилась, да и ответ на вопрос в сущей мелочь, но до неё не додумался сам. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По просьбе ТС формирую общий ответ:

Необходимо добавить в обработку роутинга параметр с языком:

```
$router->addRoutes('{lang}/{controller}/{action}/');
```

Таким образом, язык будет присутствовать в каждой странице, однако его может и не быть. В таком случае необходимо использовать язык по умолчанию, прописанный в конфигах приложения. Языки могут храниться как в БД (предпочитаемый вариант), так и жестко прописаны в виде массива в конфигах.

**P.S.** Это всего лишь наводки, т.к. роутингом давно не пользуюсь.